# mysql access denied when connecting from centos to ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to connect from my centos linux server to ubuntu linux mysql server and this is the command i am using

mysql -u username -p -h xx.xx.xx.xx(this is my ubuntu ip)

I installed mysql on centOS using

```
 yum install mysql

 // this command has actually installed mariadb
```

and I have granted permission to username@yy.yy.yy.yy and username@% to my ubuntu mysql. yy.yy.yy.yy is my centOS ip.

when I try to connect , It is showing that access denied.

Comment: When you encountered a access denied error it indicated that the connection is done, and probably the password dismatch the username@%.

Comment: password is correct

Comment: I am using same password to connect username from different machines and its working from one more machine but not from this centOS

Comment: There's nothing special about centos if that is what you are hinting at.  Are there any other network constraints like perhaps a firewall?  Do you see anything in the mysql server log when the connection fails?

Comment: I got it , I actually didnt set Identified By 'password' for this ip , I thought it should work because for "username'@'%' , I already set Identified by password

Answer (score 0):

I got it , I actually didnt set Identified By 'password' for this ip , I thought it should work because for "username'@'%' , I already set Identified by password